# How to group "unlike" elements when iterating array (e.g.:{1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,1,1} to {1,2}{2,1,3}{3}{3,2,1}{1})?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, iterator

I have array

```
int a[]={1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,1,1};
```

If I want to group the same elements when iterating them (without any temp variables or arrays to store or copy elements), for example, print same elements in a line when iterating:

```
1 
2 2 
1 
3 3 3 
2 
1 1
```

I can have for loops and if conditions like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a[]={1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,1,1};
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);i++){
        if(i==sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)-1 || a[i]!=a[i+1]){
            for(;j<=i;j++){
                printf("%d ",a[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But now I want to group "unlike" elements when iterating : each group does not have same elements nearby:

```
1 2 
2 1 3 
3 
3 2 1 
1
```

is it possible to have solution that is similar to previous version

```
for(int i=0,j=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);i++){
    if(...){
        for(;j<=i;j++){
            printf("%d ",a[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

that can iterate the array to print the result like that without any temp variables?

Comment: If an element is the same as the next element, print a `'\n'`. Be careful at the end. (Or the other way round, check if it is the same as the previous, and be careful at the beginning).

Comment: @amuse If you do not want to use any temporary variable, see my solution.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322319/what-can-be-done-to-encourage-community-involvement

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[] = {1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,1,1};

int prev = a[0];
bool first = false;
printf("%d", prev);

for (int i=1; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(int); ++i) {
    int curr = a[i];
    if (curr != prev) {
        // start a new line for a new group
        printf("\n");
        first = true;
    }
    if (!first) {
        // print a space after each element
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%d", curr);
    first = false;
    prev = curr;
}
```

Comment: `int first`: I’d rather use `bool` in C++.

Comment: @Melebius Based on the use of `printf`, and not a single `std::` in sight, I think he mistook it for a `C` question.

Comment: @BoBTFish I'm not a C++ person (by trade), but the OP was interesting to me so I attempted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can easily be solved **without any use of temporary variable** in just one iteration of the array.

The main idea is to just look behind before printing the element at current index and if they both match, then we have to place the element at current index on a new line and thats it.

The first element is printed and the loop begins from second element because there is no element behind first element.

Using this basic idea, the code for this is:

```
int a[] = {1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,1,1};
//print the first element
printf("%d ",a[0]);
for (int i=1; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(int); ++i) {
 //check if the element at current index matches previous element.
 if(a[i] == a[i-1]) 
  printf("\n%d ",arr[i]);
 else printf("%d ",arr[i]);

}
```

Comment: I almost like this, except that it will always print an extra space on every line (not the end of the world).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen try changing the first format specifier to `"%d"` and the others in the loop to `"\n%d"` and `" %d"` or use `cout << a[0];` and then `cout << '\n' << arr[i];` and `cout << ' ' << arr[i];`. And then I realize you already answered that way ;)...

Answer (score 0):

This is just begging to be solved with [`adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

For grouping unlike elements you could do:

```
auto i = cbegin(a);

for (auto j = adjacent_find(cbegin(a), cend(a)); j != cend(a); i = j, j = adjacent_find(i, cend(a))) {
    copy(i, ++j, ostream_iterator<decltype(*cbegin(a))>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
copy(i, cend(a), ostream_iterator<decltype(*cbegin(a))>(cout, " "));
```

For grouping like elements you could simply use [`not_equal_to`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_equal_to) as `adjacent_find`'s binary predicate:

```
auto i = cbegin(a);

for (auto j = adjacent_find(cbegin(a), cend(a), not_equal_to<decltype(*cbegin(a))>()); j != cend(a); i = j, j = adjacent_find(i, cend(a), not_equal_to<decltype(*cbegin(a))>())) {
    copy(i, ++j, ostream_iterator<decltype(*cbegin(a))>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
copy(i, cend(a), ostream_iterator<decltype(*cbegin(a))>(cout, " "));
```

[<kbd>Live Examples</kbd>](http://ideone.com/xVEFiX)

Note: The `decltype(*cbegin(a))` may seem a bit complex it can be substituted with `int` but, you'll lose flexibility. Right now this code requires no change if you arbitrarily want to declare `a` as a `string` or even a `set<double>`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done to solve this problem is of time complexity *O(N^2)*. But it is possible to do this problem in time complexity *O(N)*, which is explained very well in the previous answers. But I think you need to do this only by changing the `if(...)`. I found a solution here. Replace the line by the following code.

```
if( (i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int) && a[i]==a[i+1]) || i==sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)-1 )
```

You don't have to change anything else. 
 I think `(i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int) && a[i]==a[i+1])` part is very much understandable  and the `i==sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)-1` part is specially for the last element, if the last element is equal to the second last element.